# XML with mySQL and DOM

Tags: php, mysql, xml, dom

How can I get the code below to output node names that I define? As of now, it creates the nodes based on column names of an SQL table. I want to define both the columns and the nodes. Also, how can I code it so that when someone inserts data into my table it appends that data to the inserted data? E.g.:

```
Input data: "davidjmorin"
Data inserted: "http://someurl.com/davidjmorin"
```

Here is my code for the original question:

```
<?
//header('Content-type: text/xml');

$link = mysql_connect('localhost','root','IhaveAlLthEanSwers2012!');
mysql_select_db('bb_links');

$sql = "Select * from `links`";
$run = mysql_query($sql, $link);

if( $run && mysql_num_rows( $run ) ) {
$doc = new DOMDocument( '1.0' );
$doc->formatOutput = true;
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = true;

$root = $doc->createElement( 'data' );
$doc->appendChild( $root );

while( ( $fetch = mysql_fetch_assoc( $run ) )!== false ) {
    $node = $doc->createElement( 'channel' );
    $root->appendChild( $node );

    foreach( $fetch as $key => $value ) {
        createNodes( $key, $value, $doc, $node );
    }
}
$doc->save("thelinks.xml");
}
//$node = "channel";
function createNodes( $key, $value, $doc, $node ) {
$key = $doc->createElement( $key );
$node->appendChild( $key );
$key->appendChild( $doc->createTextNode( $value ) );
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking in your first question, but for your second question (which really should be split up into a second question on here), I think what you're asking is just basic [string concatenation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php). For example,

```
<?php
    $url_name = "http://www.example.com/";
    $data = $_POST['name']; //davidjmorin
    $data_to_insert = $url_name . $data;
    //Insert data into database
?>
```

Also, please don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799) (see the [red box](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)). Instead, you should learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you. If you care to learn, [this is a good PDO tutorial](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php).

I'm serious. Don't use those functions. *At all.*

Comment: great thank you @pythonscript ... Im just learning all this stuff so thank you for the info... i thnk I will go with the MySQLi...

Comment: Happy to help. Obviously, the code I provided isn't production-ready, since you should sanitise the database input with prepared statements (I assume you'll need to validate the data as well) but the links I gave you are good places to start.

Comment: If the answer, especially the portions about prepared statements, are helpful, please upvote the answer so more people see the warnings.